# Are neutrals for several circuits supposed to be connected at the panel?

Tags: electrical

I have 3 hot wires from the breaker box, 1 goes to a 3 way switch, from the 3 way 2 tracer wires go to the other 3 way switch, the lights are connected to the load terminal of the second 3 way. The 2nd hot wire from the breaker box goes to a group of 3 outlets. The 3rd hot goes to another group of 3 outlets. The neutrals for the lights and the outlets are all hooked together and go back to the fuse panel. Will this work ?

Comment: Are you in the US? I can't even begin to imagine how you'd be able to wire this if you are using current wiring products the way you've described it. If you are using current products then I suspect you are asking the question wrong or perhaps its how you described it. Perhaps if you can post some photos at each location it will help. If this is the first time you are wiring up AC you're better off hiring someone for this project and trying a smaller project first. What you've described sounds like an unbalanced circuit and could risk over current and lack proper protection for each circuit.

Comment: why are the neutrals connected together? ... please draw a diagram

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info if we are to help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Are all 3 hot wires in the same cable or conduit? Can you post photos of the fuse/breaker panel involved please?

Comment: Yes, both the panel's label, and the breakers controlling those 3 circuits (cut up Post-It notes to make flags).  There is a highly remote chance that this wiring is correct, but we need to see the panel to be sure.

Comment: Is this a 3 phase panel or single split phase (u.s. standard)